include-what-you-use suggests header that doesn't exist
When I run IWYU on the following minimal program:
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream("tmp.txt");
    return 0;
}

I get the following suggestion:
my_test.cpp should add these lines:
#include <__fwd/fstream.h>  // for ifstream

But when I add it and try to compile I get:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/MyTest.dir/my_test.cpp.o
my_test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: '__fwd/fstream.h' file not found

Is include-what-you-use seems to suggest adding an include to a header that doesn't exist? What am I missing?
Appendix: Env/repro info
I used the following CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(MyTest VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(MyTest my_test.cpp)
find_program(iwyu_path NAMES include-what-you-use iwyu OPTIONAL)
set(iwyu_options "-Xiwyu" "--mapping_file=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/iwyu.imp")
if(iwyu_path)
    set_property(TARGET MyTest PROPERTY CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE "${iwyu_path};;${iwyu_options}")
endif()

Using cmake . -G "Unix Makefiles" && make with CMake 3.29.0 and include-what-you-use 0.21 on macOS 14.4.1

Clearly a bug in whatever tool it is that you are using.

<fstream> is the right thing to include here, it is just that <fstream> doesn't need to exist and your tool is most likely pointing you to what the compiler actually uses in its place.

Reading the IWYU documentation: If fix_includes.py has suggested a private header file (such as <bits/stl_vector.h>) instead of the proper public header file (<vector>), you can fix this by inserting a specially crafted comment near top of the private file (assuming you can write to it): // IWYU pragma: private, include "the/public/file.h".

The tool is wrong.  Ignore the tool and be happy.

@DavidJones seems so, but if I just ignore it I'd have to filter its junk when trying to sieve useful output from it in the future. It's better to figure out how to make the tool work..

Caveat emptor.

If a tool is outputting junk it is a junk tool by definition.

It appears to be known that IWYU outputs some junk, and it can be either worked around by using a '.imp' mapping file, or by pragmas.
Pragmas
// IWYU pragma: no_include <__fwd/fstream.h>
#include <fstream>

Mapping file
The advantage of using a mapping file is that the rules can be shared for all our sources instead of repeating pragmas for the same problem. Also the source files aren't littered with pragmas for an additional tool.
The CMakeLists.txt needs to have
set(iwyu_options "-Xiwyu" "--mapping_file=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/iwyu.imp")
set_property(TARGET MyTest PROPERTY CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE "${iwyu_path};;${iwyu_options}")

And the mapping file here can be
[
    { include: ["@<.*fstream.h>", "private", "<fstream>", "public"] },
]

